# ambiguous column error when joining 2 tables which have the same column name

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

in my table A {ID, FID, Name , Age}

in my table B{ID, Job}

When I use

```
SELECT ID // I want to get the ID of table B //**error**//
FROM A TA JOIN B TB
ON TA.ID = TB.FID
ORDER BY TA.Name;
```

**Error**: ambiguous column name ID

Is there anyway to do that without having to rename the column name? (The Worst scenario)

Thank you

Comment: Really ID is a horrible name for an id column. TablenameId is much better. it has less ambiguity and it is easier to spot the FKs (which should have the same name) and it make life easier when you are doing reporting and can't have two columns with the same name and you want to see the ids from more than one table. Using ID is a SQL antipattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT TB.ID
FROM A TA JOIN B TB
ON TA.ID = TB.FID
ORDER BY TA.Name;
```

Use the full name (table name and column name seperated by a dot) to specifically select a column.

Your query doesn't fit your described table structure, I guess you swapped table A with table B.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT TB.ID  ...
```

You need to prefix any ambiguous column anywhere with your table alias.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to rename anything. you just need to specify the source of ambigous field in SELECT clause since such field exists in both sources (tables)